# Process exited with exit value [ce]: 129

Tags: sonarqube

CentOS 7

SonarQube 9.1

When I try to run SonarQube I get error:

```
2021.11.23 11:10:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up
2021.11.23 11:10:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up
TERM trapped.  Shutting down.
2021.11.23 11:15:16 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ce]: 129
2021.11.23 11:15:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is stopped
2021.11.23 11:15:16 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [web]: 129
2021.11.23 11:15:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is stopped
2021.11.23 11:15:16 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 129
2021.11.23 11:15:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2021.11.23 11:15:16 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

In web.log

```
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterPlugins] Register plugins
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.platform.web.SonarLintConnectionFilter@30e508e0 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/*], exclusions=[]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.platform.web.WebServiceFilter@1c7050d3 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/issues/delete_comment.*, ...], exclusions=[/api/authentication/login.*, ...]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.platform.web.WebServiceReroutingFilter@1ed51ce [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/components/bulk_update_key, ...], exclusions=[]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.plugins.PluginsRiskConsentFilter@2030590c [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/*], exclusions=[*.css, ...]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.DefaultAdminCredentialsVerifierFilter@5b3ef797 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/*], exclusions=[*.css, ...]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.InitFilter@4a267bb [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/sessions/init/*], exclusions=[]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter@76f74fd8 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/oauth2/callback/*], exclusions=[]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ResetPasswordFilter@2f2e7fee [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/*], exclusions=[*.css, ...]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction@3ccc1a60 [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/authentication/login], exclusions=[]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LogoutAction@3adf4fba [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/authentication/logout], exclusions=[]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.ValidateAction@12405eaf [pattern=UrlPattern{inclusions=[/api/authentication/validate], exclusions=[]}]
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.ProjectsInWarningDaemon] Counting number of projects in warning is not started as there are no projects in this situation.
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.p.PlatformLevelStartup] Running Community Edition
2021.11.23 11:10:01 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] WebServer is operational
2021.11.23 11:15:15 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Gracefully stopping process
2021.11.23 11:15:16 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service stopped
2021.11.23 11:15:16 INFO  web[][o.s.s.app.WebServer] WebServer stopped
```